# Mercurial Log Templates

Tags: mercurial

I have created a log alias in `.hgrc` file

```
nlog = glog --style=${HOME}/.hg-ext/templates.lg
```

Now in the `templates.lg` I use `label` function to colorize output

```
changeset = "{label('red',rev)} {label('c.author', author|person)} {desc|firstline|strip} {label('green', date|age)} {label('yellow', branches)}{label('yellow',bookmarks)}{label('yellow', tags)}\n\n"

changeset_verbose = "{label('red',rev)}:{node|short} {label('c.author',author|person)} {desc|firstline|strip} {label('green',date|age)} {label('yellow', branches)}{label('yellow',bookmarks)}{label('yellow', tags)}\n\n"

start_branches = " "
branch = "{label('yellow', branch)}"

start_bookmarks = " "
bookmark = "{label('yellow', bookmark)}, "
last_bookmark = "{label('yellow', bookmark}"

start_tags = " "
tag = "{label('yellow', tag)}, "
last_tag = "{label('yellow', tag)}"
```

When I run `hg nlog` it works ok on some repositories, but fails on others with follwing trace

```
C:\Users\esharapov\Repos\Composer.Hg>hg -v --traceback nlog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 191, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 924, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 681, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 195, in closure
  File "hgext\color.pyo", line 518, in colorcmd
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 195, in closure
  File "hgext\pager.pyo", line 143, in pagecmd
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1055, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1015, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 921, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 991, in check
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 537, in __call__
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 991, in check
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 195, in closure
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 991, in check
  File "hgext\mq.pyo", line 3516, in mqcommand
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 991, in check
  File "hgext\graphlog.pyo", line 64, in glog
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5076, in log
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 2219, in graphlog
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 2196, in displaygraph
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 1184, in show
  File "mercurial\cmdutil.pyo", line 1489, in _show
  File "mercurial\templatefilters.pyo", line 340, in stringify
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 802, in increasingchunks
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 783, in _flatten
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 262, in runtemplate
  File "hgext\color.pyo", line 501, in templatelabel
  File "mercurial\templatefilters.pyo", line 340, in stringify
  File "mercurial\templatekw.pyo", line 115, in _showlist
  File "mercurial\templatekw.pyo", line 106, in one
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 938, in __call__
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 845, in process
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 835, in _load
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 181, in compiletemplate
  File "mercurial\templater.pyo", line 173, in _parsetemplate
  File "mercurial\parser.pyo", line 78, in parse
  File "mercurial\parser.pyo", line 70, in _parse
  File "mercurial\parser.pyo", line 50, in _parseoperand
  File "mercurial\parser.pyo", line 41, in _match
ParseError: ('unexpected token: end', 26)
hg: parse error at 26: unexpected token: end
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a single revision or set of revisions that cause the problem at all?

Comment: BTW, `label('c.author'` doesn't colorize author-name - I coudn't find `c.author` definitions at all

Comment: Yeah, I had some color setup in `.hgrc` file `[color]` section that I didn't want to include and hastily did search/replace on SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't show you your mistake, but I performed some additional tests with strict correlations between condition and result

### Preparation

- Created `$TortoiseHg\templates\map-cmdline.colorglog` with content, identical to your `templates.lg` (I'm too lazy to write your long command on every test)
- Found command-line in my 3.7.1, equivalent to your `nlog` (because `hg: unknown command 'glog'`): it's

  > hg log -G --style=colorglog

log -G and style without path, because style-file in default map-location with *good* name

- Enabled Color Extension

### Testing

**Repo without tags (except mandatory `tip`) or bookmarks**

```
>hg paths
default = https://bitbucket.org/albert_brand/hgexportfiles
>hg tags
tip                               10:ee40a7b06166

>hg book
no bookmarks set
```

hg log - OK

**Repo with tags and bookmarks**

```
>hg paths
default = http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/

>hg book
   master                    987:be0d1413a06f
   next                      490:ac644c0e16d4

>hg tags
tip                              987:be0d1413a06f
0.8.5                            985:53d514c9c7e6
0.8.4                            976:22a12bf143a3
0.8.3                            946:d7ad67f850b2
0.8.2                            926:e183fdc198f0
0.8.1                            902:e6489cf3fe8c
0.8.0                            857:cf3dafce0611
0.7.0                            827:fc63d0e2653d
...
```

hg log - FAIL ("hg: parse error at 26: unexpected token: end")

**Repo with tags and without bookmarks**

```
>hg paths
default = http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/

>hg book
no bookmarks set

>hg tags
tip                             1378:e1619c051788
1.8.5                           1370:bd979667611d
1.8.4                           1365:89997a5fc181
1.8.3                           1347:759cafce6bec
1.8.2                           1344:38be7a6b6def
1.8.1                           1324:dde1ade36a49
...
```

hg log - OK

**Additional tests with single tagged|bookmarked revisions in hg-git gepo**

```
>hg log -r 985 --style=colorglog
985 Siddharth Agarwal init: mark Mercurial 3.7 as supported and prepare for 0.8.5 6 weeks ago  0.8.5
```

Tagged revision - OK

```
>hg log -r 490 --style=colorglog
hg: parse error at 26: unexpected token: end
```

Bookmarked revision - FAIL

---

## ADDITION

OK, I catched it. As usual, obvious typo in obvious place. Instead of

```
last_bookmark = "{label('yellow', bookmark}"
```

it must be

```
last_bookmark = "{label('yellow', bookmark)}"
```

for obvious reason: `label()`, not `label(`

and bookmarked revision will not generate error anymore

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's a lot of work. Does it mean that color extension is not compatible with bookmarks in the repo ?

Comment: @EvgeniySharapov - no, it means only "something is bad in your style": I can get colored output from `hg log -r 490` with just default style+extension enabled. No, I don't know, how to fix your style

Comment: Ok. Thank you for finding it out.